# Swing : Exit application actionListener

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to figure out how can we exit the application with button click.
The problem i faced which makes me unable to exit the application is because i am using "extend JFRame" from the main class.

For an example,

**app.class**

```
public class app{
  public static void main(String[] args){
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
   JFrame frame = new MainFrame("Exercise one");
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   .. .. ..
   frame.setVisible(true); 
   })
  }
}
```

**MainFrame.java**

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame(){
 public MainFrame(String title){
  super(title)

      //set layout manager
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

     //swing components
    JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");

    //add container 
    Container container = getContentPane();

    container.add(exit);

   //create actionlist logic 
    exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()){
    @Override 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
          // on click , this logic will end the application
     }
    }

  }
}
```

I fully understand how i can cancel the application from app class.But in scenarios where i want to cancel the application from MainFrame.Can it be done ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try, `setVisible(false)`?

Comment: 2 options. 1st is calling `dispose()` which will close the gui and 2. is `System.exit()` which will stop whole program

Comment: @matt
Hi matt, using setVisible(false) wont be the correct way. reason being , it will still run and it wont kill the application completely. But thanks anw :)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer
Hi , thank you so much , ive tried dispose(). This work perfectly . But as for System.exit(). it does not work as it states the type of system  is not applicable . .. but thank you so much :)

Comment: The `defaultCloseOperation` is only handled by the `WINDOW_CLOSING` event, which neither `setVisible` or `dispose` will trigger

Comment: @FaridAvesko `java.lang.System.exit(0);` would be the proper syntax, but look at MadProgrammer's answer as its very good and accurate

Answer (score 2):

The `defaultCloseOperation` is only processed by the frame when it encounters a `WINDOW_CLOSING` event, neither `setVisible` or `dispose` trigger this event, which means the the `defaultCloseOperation` won't be processed

The only way to ensure that this operation is triggered is to manually dispatch a `WINDOW_CLOSING` event

```
frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

One of the main reasons for wanting to follow this path is that it ensures the application is following the configured `defaultCloseOperation` and making up it's own mind (like calling `System.exit` manually)

The following demonstrates hiding, disposing and dispatching approaches.  Only the dispatch approach will close the window and terminate the JVM

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import static javax.swing.Action.NAME;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

                frame.add(new JButton(new HideAction(frame)), gbc);
                frame.add(new JButton(new DisposeAction(frame)), gbc);
                frame.add(new JButton(new DispatchAction(frame)), gbc);
                frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("Closing");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("Closed");
                    }
                });
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class HideAction extends AbstractAction {

        private JFrame frame;

        public HideAction(JFrame frame) {
            this.frame = frame;
            putValue(NAME, "Hide");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.setVisible(false);
        }

    }

    public class DisposeAction extends AbstractAction {

        private JFrame frame;

        public DisposeAction(JFrame frame) {
            this.frame = frame;
            putValue(NAME, "Dispose");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class DispatchAction extends AbstractAction {

        private JFrame frame;

        public DispatchAction(JFrame frame) {
            this.frame = frame;
            putValue(NAME, "Dispatch");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
        }

    }
}
```

If I run this in my IDE, unless I use the dispatch option, the JVM is left running and I have to terminate the session to close it fully.

I also noted that calling `dispose` only triggers the `WINDOW_CLOSED` event, while the dispatch method will trigger the `WINDOW_CLOSING` event

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved.** 
Credits to @XtremeBaumer.

Basically, when using "classname" extend JFRame.
We can input dispose() which will kill the application completely. This will causes the JFrame window to be destroyed and cleaned up by the operating system. :)

Comment: `dispose` doesn't trigger the `defaultCloseOperation` processing, calling it will not terminate the JVM in the same way as a user clicking the [X] button on the window's title bar

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, dispose() is the right solution. I also suggest to add a pack() call so the UI shows up properly:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    public MainFrame(String title) {
        super(title);

        ...

        // create actionlist logic
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("--> closing app programmatically");
                MainFrame.this.dispose();
            }
        });
        this.pack();

    }
}
```

You can test the events with a `WindowListener` on the `MainFrame`. They are invoked as if the user pressed the close button:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new MainFrame("Exercise one");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            // .. .. ..
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("--> closing...");
                }

                public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("--> closed...");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `dispose` doesn't trigger the `defaultCloseOperation` processing, calling it will not terminate the JVM in the same way as a user clicking the [X] button on the window's title bar

Comment: Okay... What's the observable difference?

Comment: One will hide the window and allow the jvm to continue to run (not processing the settings of the defaultCloseOperation), the other will allow the frame to process the defaultCloseOperation and if set, will terminate the jvm. Using the dispatch process will do the same thing as if the user clicked the [X] button on the window frame